# I have a trouble with an integration from a book of kinetic gas theory.

Tags: integration

How integrating this expression:
$$
\text{dn}=-n(x) N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right){}^2\text{dx}
$$

in order to evolves into this:

$$
n(x)= N_0 e^{ -N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right){}^2x}
$$

Or how integrating this along a distance *d*:
$$
\text{dn}=\text{$\alpha $n} \text{dx}
$$
Evolves into this:
$$
n=n_{0 }e^{\text{$\alpha $d}}
$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Differential_equation

Comment: Do you know how to integrate $\int \frac{dx}{x}$?

Comment: This comes from the fact that the derivative of $e^{cx}$ is $ce^{cx}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I suppose that you know that the derivative of a exponential function $y=e^{ax}$ is $\dfrac {dy}{dx}=ae^{ax}=ay$ and your equation is just of this tipe:

$d n=\alpha n\, dx \Rightarrow \dfrac{dn}{dx}=\alpha n$

Answer (score 0):

As $\frac{dn}{dx}(x) = \alpha n(x)$, $n$ is a solution of the first order linear differential equation
$$y' = \alpha y$$
It means that there is a constant $n_0 = n(0)$ such as
$$n(x) = n_0e^{\alpha x}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your first expression, $n$ depends on $x$. So for more clarity, I'd rewrite it as
$$
dn(x)=-n(x) N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2\ dx
$$
Also note that $N, \pi, r_1$ and $r_2$ are constants. So now we have
$$
\frac{1}{n(x)}\ dn(x)=-N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2\ dx
$$
$$
\int\frac{1}{n(x)}\ dn(x)=-N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2\int dx
$$
$$
\ln\left|n(x)\right|=-N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2x+C
$$
$$
n(x)=e^{-N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2x+C}
$$
$$
n(x)=e^Ce^{-N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2x}
$$
$$
n(x)=Ce^{-N \pi \left(r_1+r_2\right)^2x}
$$
Where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.